# Web Application with using System.Web.Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

I have a ASP.NET C# web application that uses `System.Web.Routing`.

For some reason I cannot catch all HTTP errors. For example:

- www.domain.com/adfasdf/asfadf/ - correctly redirects to custom page
- www.domain.com/fafad/afdad/asfaf/ - returns the default error page that looks like:

[image: 404 page sample]

web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="Page-Not-Found"/>      
</customErrors>
```

I am not able to catch those errors in the `Global.asax` file.

Is there anyway to redirect user to the error page for any error (handled and unhandled) under root site?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<system.webserver>
...
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
...
</system.webserver>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Web.Config,

Add following sections to handle errors

```
<system.webServer>
...
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>   
        <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />  
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Error404.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
        <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Error500.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />  
    </httpErrors>
...
</system.webServer>
```

and

```
<system.web>
...
<customErrors defaultRedirect="/Error" mode="RemoteOnly">
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Error500.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error404.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
...
</system.web>
```